# VSCODE flutter is repeatedly asking to be run from xcode

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, visual-studio-code

The vscode IDE keeps repeatedly ask to be run from xcode, It is intermittent and some times it will run while most of the time it keeps asking to be run from xcode. This is very frustrating. work find on xcode in one run where as takes atleast 4-5 time before it actually runs on real device from VSCODE

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Pannam 10.5 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: FTSSDSD68A
Xcode build done.                                           45.0s
Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 64710b4b6289ef663692fc70dfa0912fdcc7a0ce.
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on Pannam 10.5.
Exited
```

Comment: Try launching it once from xcode. There might be some simulator related issue or some licence agreement related issue which you might need to accept from xcode.

Comment: everything is fine, i do run it from xcode, then only it will run from vscode. sometimes it will run without running from xcode.